How to Perform Clustering with OpenAI Embeddings Alongside Other Variables?
I’m working on a clustering project where my dataset includes both traditional variables (numerical and categorical features) and embeddings of multiple variables generated by OpenAI models. My goal is to perform clustering that takes into account both the embeddings and the other variables.
My questions are:

What is the best way to combine OpenAI embeddings with other variables for clustering purposes and them self?
Is it appropriate to simply concatenate the embeddings with the other features?
Are there specific techniques or algorithms that are more suitable for handling this type of mixed data (embeddings and traditional variables)?

I have considered reducing the dimensionality of the embeddings using PCA or t-SNE before combining them. I’m also aware of the importance of scaling and normalizing the variables so that none dominate the clustering process.
Any advice, suggestions, or examples would be greatly appreciated!
